# Get remaining Events/Messages from pipeline if channel was closed

Tags: logging, netty

at the moment I'm working on a project about tracking gps-devices. Because they comunicate over TCP with a custom (binary data containing, html like) protocol, netty was the first choice. But now we are encountering some serious problems.

Because we had to log all received data enhanced by debug prints to different files depending on connected devices, we introduced a LogEvent extending ChannelStateEvent. This was the only suitible way we found to accomplish logging from everywhere in the pipeline to a specific file.

Logging now basically works like:
    channel.getPipeline().sendUpstream(new LogEvent(channel, record))

For simplification and to get all features of modern logging APIs we wrapped this in a custom class ChannelLogger that we can use like:

```
ChannelLogger.fine(channel, "...");
ChannelLogger.info(channel, "...");
ChannelLogger.warn(channel, "...", [Throwable]);
```

My question is,
how to get the LogEvents remaining in the pipeline if the channel was closed?

```
// handler 1
ChannelLogger.warn(channel, ...);
...
// handler 2
channel.close();
```

Closing is done immediately, so all remaining data in the pipeline is discarded, thus our log-events (mostly errors describing why the channel was closed) too.

Thanks in advance, Eric

Answer (score 2):

First of why yo not just add a SimpleChannelHandler and override every method in it and do the logging there ? This will also safe you some allocation as you not need to fire an extra event for everything.

Now to your question... This should do the trick:

```
channel.write(ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

Comment: Why I not just add a SimpleChannelHandler and override every method is because we'll log from within every ChannelHandler in the pipeline to only one specific logging handler per channel which can differ by type of protocol.
Writing an empty buffer to the pipeline does not work at all, my LogEvents are moving upward not downward through the pipeline, thus this future will complete when it was sent. I thought downstream works independently from the upstream or did I missed something?
But the idea is great! At the moment I'm using the same technic upwards on test platform and it looks better...

Comment: you are right.. I missunderstood you and thought about you need to make sure you write everything out before close the channel

Comment: We now reimplemented the hole thing with ChannelLocals... Nearly the same structure but much more complecated handling... but it works now.
Thanks for you answer!